# H1 image replace alternative

Tags: css, image, header, seo, replace

I'm looking to add an h1 element to my header, however I am using  tags in the header (not background images) that replace each other when the screen resolution changes.

I've looked at the technique

```
<h1 class="technique-four">
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/header-image.jpg" alt="CSS-Tricks" />
</a>
</h1>


h1.technique-four {
width: 350px; height: 75px;
background: url("images/header-image.jpg");
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

...but since my layout is fluid, the background can be seen when the image changes.

Is it even necessary to replace the h1 with an image? couldn't I just do something like:

```
<h1 class="headerhone">kb-k bwf-kb</h1> 

<a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/720.jpg" class="show-on-phones"/></a>

<a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/980_full.jpg" class="hide-on-phones"alt=""/></a>
```

(ignore the php)

and then give h1 a height of zero:

```
h1.headerhone{
height:0px;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;

} /*this was suggested to me as an alternative to the -9999px; thing.*/
```

would this work? Would it have any negative SEO implications or usability issues?

Answer (score 0):

In the second solution, on a screen reader, your h1 content will be "kb-k bwf-kb" and the screen reader won't understand the `alt` property of the following image is in fact your h1.

For Google, this second solution'll seem you want to hide content in h1 tag : bad.

A visual example would be useful, I don't understand all you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Google has never had anything positive to say about hiding text and using images in `<h1>` tags so I always hesitate to recommend that as a solution. Your last technique would almost certainly fall under serving up different content to search engines so I also recommend against it.

Your second idea is on the right track though. What you want to do is use [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design) to determine the width of your layout and adjust the image accordingly. In fact, [Google has been writing a lot about it in their blog lately](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com). I highly recommend learning how to do it.